# How in experimental practice does a momentum measurement reduce a state to a momentum eigenfunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-measurements

It's easy to think of ways to reduce the state of a particle to a position eigenfunction (or at least a narrow spread in position space), whether by trapping the particle in a potential well or by striking it with a probe photon, and we can calculate the precision $\Delta x$ necessary to produce an experimentally significant $\Delta p$ through the [x,p] uncertainty relation. However, despite how much emphasis there is in QM texts on position and momentum eigenfunctions and the [x,p] uncertainty relation, I have not come across an example of an actual experiment in which a momentum measurement could reduce a state to a momentum eigenfunction, with corresponding spread in the position state in accordance with the uncertainty relation. For example in HEP momentum is measured through sequential position measurements in order to establish radius of curvature, but clearly you cannot produce momentum eigenstates by measuring position! Similarly for time-of-flight measurements, or anything else I can think of. Diffraction could be used to establish the expectation value of wavelength (and thus momentum) with an *ensemble* of identically prepared states, but you can't measure a diffraction pattern with a single particle!

Can someone point out any experiment that measures particle momentum with the result of leaving the state in a momentum eigenfunction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [collimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimator) to filter out particles with wrong direction, and then use a narrow band-pass filter. Such a filter can be made using interference to reflect particles with wavevector outside of the passband. For photons this is typically implemented in [photonic crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_crystal), for electrons a [superlattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlattice) can be made.

Comment: Doesn't collimation produce diffraction by constraining position in exactly the kind of way that would make it impossible to end up with a momentum eigenstate?

Comment: @user1247 not necessarily so. If the collimator's aperture is much wider than wavelength of the particle, then diffraction on the output can be negligible. You just have to make sure that the length of the collimator is still sufficient to let the collimator absorb the off-axis particles.

Comment: @user1247 has a good point, we are talking *eigenstate* here, so the spread in position should be infinitely large. A collimator will not allow for that. However the reality is that measurement is not exactly as is written in textbooks and a momentum eigenfunction is never produced after a measurement.

Comment: This begs the question, what *is* produced after measurement? Humanity doesn't really have a good answer for that yet. Of the proposals I have seen so far, the only QM framework without a measurement problem is Bohmian Mechanics. There, there is no need for wave functions to collapse.

Comment: @doublefelix humanity does have an answer, but you may be dissatisfied with it: it depends on exactly how you measure the state. And if you fail to describe the whole state vector of the system and observer, you're limited to a mixed state of the system after measurement. Bohmian mechanics doesn't really give any more information than CI or MWI or any other interpretation—just adds a pseudo-classical picture that could satisfy some people without actually explaining anything.

Comment: You can describe the whole state vector of the system and observer, but you will get a superposition of the system with the detector which doesn't reflect the fact that measuring the state again should get the same result as the first measurement. Thus the exact wave function alone after measurement is insufficient to make predictions after the measurement. What should be done with it though, exactly? It's easy to say "cut off one branch", but how exactly? At what point during the measurement process? Do you apply a projector to the system or to some part of the apparatus? Which part?

Comment: Those questions have only a small impact on the resulting wave function, but one which is measurable in principle (and sometimes in practice: for example, a sharp cutoff in position space leaves a strong dent in the fourier transform). The only _continuous_ resolution to this I have seen is in Bohmian Mechanics, but it's a bit long to explain in a comment. In case you fear I am a dogmatic Bohmian trying to convert you, have no fear; I'm agnostic w.r.t. interpretation because I think these things are just generally not understood and I'm just stating what I have understood so far.

Comment: @doublefelix actually I'm confused with this conversation. What are we talking about – measurement or preparation? These are different procedures and require different manipulations of the wavefunction of the system&observer (in the former case you need all the meaningful outcomes, while in the latter you only take the outcome you wanted (well, approximation to it)).

Comment: I meant measurement

Comment: So in order to make an efficient measuring device out of this we’d need to use multiple of these with different pass filters? Because as of now it’s more of a momentum selector than a momentum measurer.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish multiple of these, or just rotate one to scan through the directions of momenta, use a variable-passband filter to scan through the magnitudes. Measurement of an observable by filtering is not unheard of: e.g. spectrum of light can be measured using a [linear variable filter](https://www.deltaopticalthinfilm.com/linear-variable-filters/) instead of splitting a light beam by a diffraction grating.